# Event trigger for Shift + Left Click

Tags: wpf, mvvm, eventtrigger

I have a button in `WPF`.

When pressed, it activates the `ViewModel` Command : `myBtnClick`.

```
 <Button Command="{Binding myBtnClick}" />
```

It works fine.

I want to run another command when press **Shift + Left Click**

Is there a way to do this with `Event Trigger`?

**(I want to keep the principles of `MVVM`)**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You just need to define [`InputBindings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings) for your `Button`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding myBtnClick}">
   <Button.InputBindings>
       <MouseBinding Gesture="Shift+LeftClick" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
   </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

Comment: It works fine. The problem that remains is that he also comes to the Command of the usual click on Shift + LeftClick. There is way to disable this?

Comment: I've just tested that and if you hold `Shift` during click then it does not go into `Click` command. It goes there if I do `Shift + Double Click`. You can always remove `Command="{Binding myBtnClick}"` and add another `InputBinding` specificly for `LeftClick` `<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding myBtnClick}"/>`

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a question that is not related to the subject, is there a way in Command, to know if Press Shift? (without Command parameter - is already in use)

Comment: Sure there is. `Keyboard` has static [`Modifiers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers.aspx) that gives you current state of keys like `Alt`, `Control`, `Shift` or `Windows`. Just use something like `Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift)`